# Python 3 requests library and json within a list

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-requests

For example I have this json response:

```
response = '{"data" : {"next_Data" : { "actual_data" :["data1", "data2", "data3"]}}}'
```

In my usual approach to a big amount of json, I do this:

```
import requests

for x in response.json()['data']['next_Data']:
    print x['actual_data']

#Output
>>> 'data1'
>>> 'data2'
>>> 'data3'
```

Now how do I **manipulate the code to display which ever 'actual_data' I want?** For example, I want the first record (in this case 'data1') to be the only one to be extracted..or I want the 3rd data ('data3') be the only one extracted..how do I do  this?

Thanks a lot guys,

Drew

Comment: Put it into a dict and manipulate it from there?  Or is it so huge that this is not feasible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to fill out your code snippet a little more for future visitors with the same question. (Your snippet, by the way, will not print what you think it will.) It would look something like:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://example.com')
actual_data = requests.json()['data']['next_Data']['actual_data']

for x in actual_data:
    print x

# prints on separate lines data1, data2, data3


print actual_data
# prints ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
print actual_data[0]
# prints data1
print actual_data[2]
# prints data3
print actual_data[1]
# prints data2
print actual_data[-1]
# prints data3
print actual_data[-2]
# prints data2
print actual_data[-3]
# prints data1
```

That's how you would access you array of data (actually a list as far as Python is concerned) once you have the array.

The access you described above, `response.json()['data']['next_Data']` would return `{'actual_data': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']}` and doing a for loop on that dictionary/hash/object would yield the key: `'actual_data'` and trying `x['actual_data']` would give you a TypeError since the indices are supposed to be integers.